# PyQt5 - Ubuntu 18.04 - Error 99 on QNetworkReply when request to HTTPS url

Tags: python-3.x, https, pyqt5, qnetworkreply, ubuntu-18.04

I'm building an app using **Python 3.6** and PyQt5.
I was on **Ubuntu 16.04** I used to make HTTP request using QNetworkReply and QNetworkRequest from QtNetwork like so :

```
@pyqtSlot('QNetworkReply*')
def receiveReply(self, reply):
    buffer = reply.readAll()
    if (reply.error() != QNetworkReply.NoError):
        print("API - Error  " + str(reply.error()) + " : " + buffer.data().decode('utf8'))
        self.networkManager.clearAccessCache()
    else:
        print('yeah !')
    reply.deleteLater()

@pyqtSlot()
def sendRequest(self):
        request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.fr"))
        self.networkManager.get(request)
```

(I'm showing a simplified version of my code that still throw the error) 
Since I upgraded my OS to **Ubuntu 18.04** I'm getting an error 99 (QNetworkReply::**UnknownNetworkError**) from the QNetworkReply everytime I'm making a request to a **HTTPS** url.
But if, in the example, I replace https://www.google.fr by http://www.google.fr it works perfectly.
I'm guessing it has to deal with HTTPS url in general but I can't find why it's happening on Ubuntu 18.
Thanks in advance if someone can help me !

Comment: since you have installed PyQt5, have you done it with apt-get or with pip or from the source code? Most likely, when you compiled the PyQt5 that you use, I do not add the option to use openssl, and the https pages need it

Comment: I installed it with pip.

Comment: The thing is I don't really know how to add the option of openssl with pyqt5

Comment: There are 2 options: install from ubuntu repos: sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 or install it from the source code.

Comment: The first solution works thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc), here is the solution :

```
pip3 uninstall pyqt5
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```